# Error in description method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

What is wrong here ?

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return self.name;    
}
```

Compiler gives me an error "Property name not found on object of type ..."

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the corresponding class declaration?

Comment: @Bavarious, I have no declaration for description class

Comment: That is an instance method, which means you’re implementing that method as part of a class, which means you need either a class or a (ugh!) category declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Since `-description` is an instance method, `self` points to the current instance of whichever class is implementing that method. Consequently, `self.name`, being equivalent to `[self name]`, expects an instance method called `-name`, potentially the getter method of a declared property called `name`. For example:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize name;
- (NSString *)description {
    return self.name;
}
@end
```

On the other hand, if you want to return the corresponding class name inside `-description`:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want class name, eh?

Then change your code to

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([myObject class]); 
    return(className);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not declared 'name' as NSString property and/or have not synthesized it.

--- EDIT ----

Please try as Michael has suggested! In your case it should be-

```
- (NSString *)description
{
   return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
```

Comment: I thought self.name should return class name.

Comment: @jingo: Why should it do that? The name of a class is not the same thing as the name of an instance. An instance has no name unless you give it one, which you would do by declaring and implementing a `name` property. Even if you do, giving every instance the name of its class is not very useful. If you want the name of the object's class, ask it for its class and pass that to `NSStringFromClass`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class's name, you need **not** override the description method. If you really need the class's name in the description method then:

```
return [NSString stringWithCString:class_className([self class]);
```

you would need to

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

For more information see [Objective C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)